# Pass nullable argument to a method

Tags: c#, nullable

This my current method but from time to time I have to deal with this problem and I want to know if there is more elegant way.

I have : `long? LoadEntityId` field. I have a method where I use this as an argument :

```
private bool IsUsedInProduction(long? loadEntityId)
```

The problem is that when `LoadEntityId` is actually null I get `Nullable object must have a value.`

What I do now is this :

```
if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10
    && LoadEntityId.HasValue 
    && IsUsedInProduction(LoadEntityId.Value))
```

But I think there should be better way to manage this problem.

P.S

It seems I wasn't clear enough in my explanation so the problem is that if I:

```
if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10
        && IsUsedInProduction(LoadEntityId.Value))
```

(remove LoadEntityId.HasValue check) when LoadEntityId is actually null I get exception, if I leave it - well I just look for a way to make my code work without this check.

Comment: What's wrong with that code exactly?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown about the nullable value?

Comment: Why are you checking for a value when the argument is nullable anyway? Can't you just use `if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10 && IsUsedInProduction(LoadEntityId))`

Comment: When I comment `LoadEntityId.HasValue` which is what I want to do - remove this from the `if statement` the error is thrown inside the `if statment` :  ` if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10/* && LoadEntityId.HasValue */&& IsMaterialUsed(LoadEntityId.Value))`. More specificly - `IsMaterialUsed(LoadEntityId.Value))` - here. I just want to know if there's some way to pass null as it seems I can't do it naturally even though my method accepts `long?`

Comment: Then Lee is correct, just ommit the `.Value` to `IsUsedInProduction`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you use the right approach.

there are three options:

1) check loadEntityId.HasValue and then work with loadEntityId.Value (what you use now)

2) use loadEntityId.GetValueOrDefault()

```
if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10
    && IsUsedInProduction(loadEntityId.GetValueOrDefault()))
```

3) use ?? operator

```
if ((byte)cboStatus.SelectedValue == 10
    && (IsUsedInProduction(loadEntityId ?? 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare:

```
private bool IsUsedInProduction(long? loadEntityId)
```

is actually the same as:

```
private bool IsUsedInProduction(Nullable<long> loadEntityId)
```

So when you pass `null` to the method, an Nullable type object is created, where `loadEntityId.HasValue` is equal to `false` and `loadEntityId.Value` throws and Exception when called, because the is no value. Bellow there is an example of reasonable use of Nullable. Additional Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

**Definition example:**

```
private bool IsUsedInProduction(long? loadEntityId)
{
     if(loadEntityId.HasValue)
     {
        //do something WITH loadEntityId.Value
     } else
     {
        //do something
     }
}
```

**Calling examples:**

```
IsUsedInProduction(null);
IsUsedInProduction(21);
IsUsedInProduction(23);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but I think the answer may be the ?? operator:

```
if(loadEntity ?? -1 > 0){...}
```

This means that the value of loadEntity is used if it has one, if it's null then the value -1 is used instead.